# Meaning of '4:1 (3:0)' as score in football (World Cup match)

Tags: football, world-cup, scoring

I'm looking at [Fifa data on the France vs Mexico World Cup match](https://www.fifa.com/worldcup/matches/round=201/match=1096/index.html#nosticky) in 1930, the score is presented as 4:1 (3:0). Looking at the 'goals scored' section I see 5 goals have been scored, all of them in regular playing time. So my question is, what does the the (3:0) mean?

I figured it might be something related to do with how points are awarded in the group stage of the tournament, but another match ([USA vs Belgium](https://www.fifa.com/worldcup/matches/round=201/match=1090/index.html)) which was also part of the group match has score '3:0 (2:0)' so I don't think that's it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parenthetical shows the halftime score.  This is confirmed from the list of scores:

> **Lucien LAURENT (FRA) 19'**
>
> **Marcel LANGILLER (FRA) 40'**
>
> **Andre MASCHINOT (FRA) 43'**
>
> Juan CARRENO (MEX) 70'
>
> Andre MASCHINOT (FRA) 87'